# Как сделать анимацию меню при смене блоков?

Tags: html, jquery, css, flexbox, меню

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы логотип появлялся также как и пропадает? 
Либо второй вариант чтобы он плавно переезжал налево и после него шли пункты меню и точно также плавно возвращался. 
Можно ли сделать на flex`ах?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('.main_menu').attr('class', 'main_menu_scroll'), $('.head').attr('class', 'head_scroll');
    $('.head').attr('class', 'head_scroll'), $('.head').attr('class', 'head_scroll');
    $('.head').attr('class', 'head_scroll'), $('.head').attr('class', 'head_scroll');
    $('.head').attr('class', 'head_scroll'), $('.head').attr('class', 'head_scroll');
    $('.head').attr('class', 'head_scroll'), $("header").addClass("header_scroll");
    $('.menu').attr('class', 'menu_scroll'), $('.logo').attr('class', 'logo_scroll'), $('.head img').attr('class', 'head_scroll img');
  } else {
    $('.main_menu_scroll').attr('class', 'main_menu'), $('.head_scroll').attr('class', 'head');
    $('.head_scroll').attr('class', 'head'), $('.head_scroll').attr('class', 'head');
    $('.head_scroll').attr('class', 'head'), $('.head_scroll').attr('class', 'head');
    $('.head_scroll').attr('class', 'head'), $('.head_scroll').attr('class', 'head');
    $('.head_scroll').attr('class', 'head'), $("header").removeClass("header_scroll");
    $('.menu_scroll').attr('class', 'menu'), $('.logo_scroll').attr('class', 'logo'), $('.head_scroll img').attr('class', 'head img');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Open Sans, Roboto, sans-serif
}

header {
  height: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.logo {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.main_menu {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.head img {
  height: 100px;
  transition: .2s;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#menu {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0 0;
}

.menu>ul,
.menu_scroll>ul {
  font-weight:
}

.menu>ul>li,
.menu_scroll>ul>li {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 160px;
  height: 1500px;
}

.head {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.top {
  background-image: url(../image/back_top.jpg);
  background-size: 1170px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 1170px;
  height: 656px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* для скролла */

.main_menu_scroll,
.head_scroll {
  text-align: unset;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main_menu_scroll {
  height: 100px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu_scroll {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.header_scroll {
  height: 100px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.logo_scroll {
  height: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu_scroll {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.head_scroll img {
  height: 0;
  transition: .3s;
}


/* конец скролла */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="main_menu">
    <div class="head">
      <div class="logo"><img src="https://www.aftecusa.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/manufacturer-logos/Logo-Bray-Valves-611x251-100px-border.png"></div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="menu">
          <ul id="menu">
            <li>Главная</li>
            <li>Главная</li>
            <li>Главная</li>
            <li>Главная</li>
            <li>Главная</li>
            <li>Главная</li>
            <li>Главная</li>
            <li>Главная</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="top"></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из того что вы предложили, сделал первое, и ваш html я не трогал. Пользуйтесь на здоровье.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('.main_menu').attr('class', 'main_menu_scroll'), $('.head').attr('class', 'head_scroll');
    $('.head').attr('class', 'head_scroll'), $('.head').attr('class', 'head_scroll');
    $('.head').attr('class', 'head_scroll'), $('.head').attr('class', 'head_scroll');
    $('.head').attr('class', 'head_scroll'), $('.head').attr('class', 'head_scroll');
    $('.head').attr('class', 'head_scroll'), $("header").addClass("header_scroll");
    $('.menu').attr('class', 'menu_scroll'), $('.logo').attr('class', 'logo_scroll'), $('.head img').attr('class', 'head_scroll img');
  } else {
    $('.main_menu_scroll').attr('class', 'main_menu'), $('.head_scroll').attr('class', 'head');
    $('.head_scroll').attr('class', 'head'), $('.head_scroll').attr('class', 'head');
    $('.head_scroll').attr('class', 'head'), $('.head_scroll').attr('class', 'head');
    $('.head_scroll').attr('class', 'head'), $('.head_scroll').attr('class', 'head');
    $('.head_scroll').attr('class', 'head'), $("header").removeClass("header_scroll");
    $('.menu_scroll').attr('class', 'menu'), $('.logo_scroll').attr('class', 'logo'), $('.head_scroll img').attr('class', 'head img');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Open Sans, Roboto, sans-serif
}

header {
  height: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.main_menu {
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
}

.head img {
  height: 100px;
  transition: .2s;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#menu {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0 0;
}

.menu>ul,
.menu_scroll>ul {
  font-weight:
}

.menu>ul>li,
.menu_scroll>ul>li {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 160px;
  height: 1500px;
}

.head {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.top {
  background-image: url(../image/back_top.jpg);
  background-size: 1170px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 1170px;
  height: 656px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* для скролла */

.main_menu_scroll,
.head_scroll {
  text-align: unset;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main_menu_scroll {
  height: 100px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu_scroll {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.header_scroll {
  height: 100px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.logo_scroll {
 
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu_scroll {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.head_scroll img {
  height: 0;
  transition: .3s;
}


/* конец скролла */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="main_menu">
    <div class="head">
      <div class="logo"><img src="https://www.aftecusa.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/manufacturer-logos/Logo-Bray-Valves-611x251-100px-border.png"></div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="menu">
          <ul id="menu">
            <li>Главная</li>
            <li>Главная</li>
            <li>Главная</li>
            <li>Главная</li>
            <li>Главная</li>
            <li>Главная</li>
            <li>Главная</li>
            <li>Главная</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="top"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое